Strange error during the use of `\newtheorem`
Yesterday I went back on adding more content to some informal notes I started to write long ago. The main file including the preamble with all definition used (and possibly something more) is shown here below:
%********************************************************************
%
%   Prontuario di matematica finanziaria
% 
%********************************************************************9
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,abbreviations,chapterprefix]{book}
%********************************************************************
%            Packages
%********************************************************************
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphics,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{cite}
\newcommand{\dm}{\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\Bsy}[1]{\ensuremath{{\boldsymbol{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\Prova}{\textbf{Dimostrazione}. }
\newcommand{\RNum}[1]{\MakeUppercase{\romannumeral #1}}
\newcommand{\qed}{\hfill$\blacksquare$\newline}
\newcommand{\VA}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{VA}}}    % Valore attuale
\newcommand{\VAN}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{VAN}}}  % Valore attuale netto
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollario}[chapter]
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{legge}{Legge}
\newtheorem{oss}{Osservazione}[chapter]
\setcounter{legge}{-1}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{thm}[chapter]{Teorema}
%\usepackage[tablegrid]{vhistory}
%\usepackage{relsize}
%\usepackage{romannum}  %Set the font size relative to the current font size
%\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc} %A range of footnote options
% \usepackage[
%     type={CC},
%     modifier={by-sa},
%     version={3.0},
% ]{doclicense}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%********************************************************************
%            Content
%********************************************************************
\author{Daniele Tampieri}
\title{Appunti di matematica finanziaria}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{introduzione}
\include{capitolo1}
\include{capitolo2}
\include{capitolo3}
%\include{capitolo4}
\bibliographystyle{aomplain}
\bibliography{2020-04-16_prontuario.bib}
\backmatter
% \begin{versionhistory}
%   \vhEntry{0.0}{16.04.2020}{Daniele Tampieri}{Creazione}
%   \vhEntry{1.1}{19.05.2023}{Daniele Tampieri}{Prima versione pubblicata}
%   \vhEntry{1.2}{22.05.2023}{Daniele Tampieri}{Correzione refusi}
%   \vhEntry{1.3}{29.05.2023}{Daniele Tampieri}{Aggiunto capitolo 5}
% \end{versionhistory}
% \doclicenseThis
\printindex
\end{document}

I run the compilation command just before start editing (I use Emacs as an IDE for the LaTeX coding) to check everything was Ok, but I got the following error message:
ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---
\@currentHref ->defn.\theHdefn 
                               
l.5 \begin{defn}\label{def:cap}
                               
--- HELP ---
TeX encountered an unknown command name. You probably misspelled the
name. If this message occurs when a LaTeX command is being processed,
the command is probably in the wrong place---for example, the error
can be produced by an \item command that's not inside a list-making
environment. The error can also be caused by a missing \documentclass
command.

The error refers to the first definition in chapter 1 of the notes, and it is really nothing special: precisely, the code is the following
\chapter{Leggi fondamentali}
\label{chap:Leggi_fondamentali}

La definizione seguente, anche se piuttosto informale, è centrale a tutta la trattazione.
\begin{defn}\label{def:cap}
  Il ``\emph{capitale}'' è una risorsa economica, un ``\emph{flusso di cassa}'', un ``\emph{bene}'',
  qualcosa che per tutti ha un ``\emph{valore}'' e che quindi si può misurare, comprare e scambiare.
\end{defn}
I termini indicati nella definizione~\ref{def:cap} verranno da ora in avanti usati come sinonimi.
Chiameremo \emph{denaro} la generica unità di misura del capitale, valore o che dir si voglia.

The Last time I edited the file (January 26) it all worked correctly: what could have happened in between the two compilations?
(P.S. Even an old git version from December 2021 gives me the same error)

Load package first, do settings and definitions later. The hyperref package patches \newtheorem in order to add anchors, but if the theorem is declared before loading hyperref the patch isn't applied.
Maybe the explicit error is due to some reorganization of the hyperref code, but the issue has been there from day 1 of your code.
%********************************************************************
%
%   Prontuario di matematica finanziaria
% 
%********************************************************************9
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,abbreviations,chapterprefix]{book}
%********************************************************************
%            Packages
%********************************************************************
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphics,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{cite}
%\usepackage[tablegrid]{vhistory}
%\usepackage{relsize}
%\usepackage{romannum}  %Set the font size relative to the current font size
%\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc} %A range of footnote options
% \usepackage[
%     type={CC},
%     modifier={by-sa},
%     version={3.0},
% ]{doclicense}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\dm}{\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\Bsy}[1]{\ensuremath{{\boldsymbol{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\Prova}{\textbf{Dimostrazione}. }
\newcommand{\RNum}[1]{\MakeUppercase{\romannumeral #1}}
\newcommand{\qed}{\hfill$\blacksquare$\newline}
\newcommand{\VA}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{VA}}}    % Valore attuale
\newcommand{\VAN}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{VAN}}}  % Valore attuale netto
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollario}[chapter]
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{legge}{Legge}
\newtheorem{oss}{Osservazione}[chapter]
\setcounter{legge}{-1}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{thm}[chapter]{Teorema}

%********************************************************************
%            Content
%********************************************************************
\author{Daniele Tampieri}
\title{Appunti di matematica finanziaria}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Alph}% to keep hyperref happy
\maketitle

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
%\pagenumbering{arabic} % unneeded

\chapter{Leggi fondamentali}
\label{chap:Leggi_fondamentali}

La definizione seguente, anche se piuttosto informale, è centrale a tutta la trattazione.

\begin{defn}\label{def:cap}
  Il ``\emph{capitale}'' è una risorsa economica, un ``\emph{flusso di cassa}'', un 
``\emph{bene}'',
  qualcosa che per tutti ha un ``\emph{valore}'' e che quindi si può misurare, 
  comprare e scambiare.
\end{defn}
I termini indicati nella definizione~\ref{def:cap} verranno da ora in avanti usati come sinonimi.
Chiameremo \emph{denaro} la generica unità di misura del capitale, valore o che dir si voglia.



%\include{introduzione}
%\include{capitolo1}
%\include{capitolo2}
%\include{capitolo3}
%\include{capitolo4}
%\bibliographystyle{aomplain}
%\bibliography{2020-04-16_prontuario.bib}
\backmatter
% \begin{versionhistory}
%   \vhEntry{0.0}{16.04.2020}{Daniele Tampieri}{Creazione}
%   \vhEntry{1.1}{19.05.2023}{Daniele Tampieri}{Prima versione pubblicata}
%   \vhEntry{1.2}{22.05.2023}{Daniele Tampieri}{Correzione refusi}
%   \vhEntry{1.3}{29.05.2023}{Daniele Tampieri}{Aggiunto capitolo 5}
% \end{versionhistory}
% \doclicenseThis
\printindex
\end{document}

I made also some other small fixes.

Thank You Enrico. Now it works perfectly

@DanieleTampieri Since now you owe me a favor, please, make the differential d italic.

Enrico (can I call you so) I cannot do this... My master would rise from the grave and harshly apostrophize me: he used the Roman "d" almost every one of his 300 papers.

well the error is a hyperref bug. It should use lazy_or instead of lazy_and in a test. But you nevertheless need to ensure that \theHdefn exists, either by moving the \newtheorem behind hyperref or by defining it manually, at least until the kernel provides suitable definitions by default.
